# GWT Progress Bar while buffering PDF content before displaying on browser

Tags: gwt, servlets, download, progress-bar

In my GWT app I have written a servlet to download/stream a PDF file.

Following is the code.

```
    protected void updateResponse(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream dataStream, long contentLength, KnownContentTypes contentType, String filename, int cacheSeconds) {

    response.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType.getTypeString());
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(contentLength));
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + cacheSeconds);


    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    try {
         ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
         while ((dataStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer); 
         }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        sendError(response);

    } 
}
```

The pdf is successfully rendered on the browser.
The problem is some pdf's are really large in size and since this is called on window.open all I see is a blank browser.

I want to display a dynamic message like '1MB of 5MB downloaded' and display/render the entire PDF file once all bytes are streamed.

Please let me know how to do this.
I am new to GWT and any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with synch request which we usually make by calling servlet with `Window.open` You have to make ajax request to calculate progress and display the response.

Take a look to this library: http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/. It is really easy to to use and works fine in most of the browsers. It uses `ajax` requests to calculate progress.

Comment: Can you please provide with a quick example. I had a look at the library looks like it's used for uploading and not downloading.